# Changing the texture filtering methodology within the same SpriteBatch Begin/End pair

Tags: xna, c#, monogame

How would I go about using changing the texture filtering method being used within the same SpriteBatch Begin/End pairing?

I have this code so far.

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, null, null, null);

spriteBatch.Draw(PixelArtTexture, new Vector2(x, y), null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, new Vector2(8, 8), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

spriteBatch.End ();
```

This draws a pixel art texture using point filtering, however I want to draw another texture using linear filtering, so how would I do that?

Comment: Create a second SpriteBatch Begin/End combo...

Comment: Ok ClassicThunder but is there a way of doing everything in the same Begin/End, Or ever change a textures filter mode?

Comment: You can do something like `this.GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearClamp`, although I don't know if it can be done with an an .Begin()/.End() block.

Comment: No that dosent even work outside of the Begin/end for some reason :/ but thanks for the comment :)

Comment: @William'MindWorX'Mariager That works only if the sort mode is `SpriteSortMode.Immediate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as the `SpriteSortMode` is `SpriteSortMode.Immediate` you can make alterations to graphics device in between draw calls which allows you to change the `ScissorRectangle`, `RasterizerState`, `SamplerStates`, ect...

Of course you lose the performance optimization from the batching; however, it is sometimes worth it if the alternative is creating many begin/end pairs.

For Example

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, null, null, null);
spriteBatch.Draw(PixelArtTexture, new Vector2(x, y), null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, new Vector2(8, 8), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

//Changing the SamplerState
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;
spriteBatch.Draw(PixelArtTexture, new Vector2(x, y), null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, new Vector2(8, 8), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

spriteBatch.End();
```

The first Draw call would use `SamplerState.PointClamp` and the second draw call would use `SamplerState.LinearWrap`.